# Batch script for fetching sub-strings having multiple decimal places

Tags: batch-file

I have a string having nomenclature as `A.B.C.D`, where;

```
A= single/2/3/4 digit number
B= single/2/3/4 digit number
C= single/2/3/4 digit number
D= single/2/3/4 digit number
```

For e.g. It can be say, `8.0.0.78` or `81.0.13.332` or `90.03.30.5467` or `1234.234.2345.1`, etc.

My requirement is to fetch A, B, C and D in separate variables, i.e.; number before the first decimal, number between 2 occurrences of decimal pairs and number after last decimal.

How I can achieve it? I have tried fetching the positions before, in-between and after decimals and fetch values between those positions, however, because of the variable length of the string, I am not able to get it through.

After I get the values, I have to compare it with values from another string and will decide which string has a higher value.

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%A in ("%theString%") do echo A=%%A, B=%%B, C=%%C, D=%%D`

Comment: It worked precisely as I required. Thanks a lot for helping me out.